# problem with sed inside sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to parse a string inside a sed command but I am getting errors.

```
sed -e "/pd begin $(echo 3:1I:1:1|sed 0,/:/{s/:/' '/})",/pd end $(echo 3:1I:1:1|sed 0,/:/{s/:/' '/})/p /tmp/hp-raid-data-harvester.out
```

I need to replace the first ':' from the string "3:1I:1:1".
It has to be in one line and can't be changed before. The string is coming from the database with string $1.

file hp-raid-data has inside those lines

```
### pd begin 3 2I:1:1 ###

Smart Array P410 in Slot 0

   array B

      physicaldrive 2I:1:1
         Port: 2I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 4
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 3 TB
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: CC4H
         Serial Number:             Z1F21GLG
         Model: ATA     ST3000DM001-9YN1
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 33
         Maximum Temperature (C): 42
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps


### pd end 3 2I:1:1 ###
```

Comment: Use variable substitution :  `${1/:/ }`

Answer (score 1):

You need a `/` delimiter ending the regexp before the comma. And you need to put quotes around the entire expression argument to `sed` because you have spaces in both regexps.

```
sed -e "/pd begin $(echo 3:1I:1:1|sed 0,/:/{s/:/' '/})/,/pd end $(echo 3:1I:1:1|sed 0,/:/{s/:/' '/})/p" /tmp/hp-raid-data-harvester.out
                                                      ^                                               ^
```